# Change host page from within contained, different-domain iframe: errors in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a iframe app. I am getting a alert that says **-error** in chrome for `top.location.href` .

```
jQuery.ajax({
          type : 'get',
          url : 'check_if_fb_data_set.php',
          success : function(response){
          if(jQuery.trim(response)  == 'success') {
            top.location.href = "http://mysite.com";
          } else {
                setTimeout(CheckIfFbDataSet,2000);
          }                     
        }, error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(errorThrown);
        }
});
```

I have tried

1. location.reload()
2. window.location.href = window.location.href;
3. document.write(' meta refresh.........');
4. document.write('< script> window.location ........ < /script>');

Third one didn't work but all 4 other gave me the same error. I don't have other ways to test.

Comment: I don't think you can change the location of the page containing the iframe from within the iframe, which seems to be what you're trying to do?

Comment: so @AnthonyGrist what do u suggest

Comment: Is the IFrame in the same domain?

Comment: Can you add to your question what you are tring to do?
Change the href of the iframe or the main window

Comment: no iframe is in a different domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that i had another ajax function with error callback which was getting triggered and there i had the `alert(textStatus +''+ errorThrown)`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
window.location = window.location;
```

or

```
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

The containing page may be placing your iframe inside a sand-box. HTML5 browsers such as Firefox and Chrome support the [sandbox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe), which can prevent exactly this type of behavior.

For example, if your page is within

```
<iframe src="url" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

but `allow-top-navigation` is **not** set, your content will not be able to change top-navigation.